# disable scroll on ion list

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I have a list of 6 items . The number of items are not going to change.

I want to adjust the list so that all the list items adjust on the screen without scrolling:

setting `scroll=false` on ion content did not help.

`Html` file looks like this:

```
 <ion-view view-title="{{deployementName}}">

<ion-nav-buttons side="right">
<button class="button button-default"  ng-click="opendateModal()">{{startDate}}</button>

<button menu-toggle="right" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
</ion-nav-buttons> 
<ion-nav-buttons side="left">
<a  class="button button-dark button-clear" ui-sref="Deployment"> <i class="icon ion-chevron-left icon-accessory"></i> </a>
</ion-nav-buttons>

<ion-side-menus>
<ion-side-menu-content>
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-balanced nav-title-slide-ios7">
</ion-nav-bar> 
<ion-content scroll="false">
<ion-list>
<ion-item>
<h2>SaleSummary-Total</h2>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
<h3>NetSale:</h3><br>
Rs.{{netAmount | number}}</ion-item>
<ion-item>
<h3>Gross Sale:</h3><br>
Rs.{{netAmount | number}}</ion-item>
<ion-item>
<h3>Discount:</h3><br>
Rs.{{discount | number}}
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
<h3> Total Bills:</h3><br>
{{billInfo.length}}
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
<h3> Avg Bills Per Sale:</h3><br>
Rs {{netAmount/billInfo.length| number:0}}
</ion-item>

</div>
    </div>
</ion-list>



<ion-slide-box  active-slide="myActiveSlide" show-pager="false"  on-slide-changed="slideHasChange($index)">
<ion-slide>
</ion-slide>
<ion-slide>
</ion-slide>
</ion-slide-box>
</ion-content>
</ion-side-menu-content>
<ion-side-menu side="right">
<header class="bar bar-header bar-royal">
  <h1 class="title">Menu</h1>
</header>
<ion-content class="has-header sidemenu">
<ion-list>
<ion-item nav-clear menu-close ng-click="logout()">
<i class="ion-person">
<button class="button-clear button-royal">Logout</button></i>
</ion-item>
<ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#">
<i class="ion-person"></i>
<button class="button-clear button-positive">Help</button>
</ion-item>
</ion-list>
</ion-content>
</ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>

</ion-view>
```

Comment: I just tested your code.The disable of vertical scrolling is working in app.

Comment: Could you please show a fiddle?

Comment: Can you show your json array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try adding `scroll="false"` to the `ion-list` dom element